# Income tax exemptions and deductions for Illinois part year resident?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, illinois

I was a resident of IN till mid-September 2021 and then I moved to IL. I want to know what type of exemptions and deductions I should be looking for in my part year IL income tax. Like in IN we used to get deduction for rents and $2000 exemption.

Please feel free to ask for clarifications.

P.S.: I will be filling as "married filing jointly". I am an international citizen with resident alien status in US.

Answer (score 2):

Illinois taxes are extremely straightforward, even for part-year residents (as I will be this year!).  You can see the form [here](https://www2.illinois.gov/rev/forms/incometax/Documents/currentyear/individual/il-1040.pdf), or even better file [electronically](https://www2.illinois.gov/rev/programs/mytax/Pages/il-1040.aspx) on their website for free.

There are very few exemptions; the main one is for dependents, documented [here](https://www2.illinois.gov/rev/questionsandanswers/Pages/851.aspx), $2375 this year.  There is no rent deduction, though there is a credit for property tax if you own; also money paid for school or saved for school, and a few other small things (see [here](https://www.creditkarma.com/tax/i/illinois-state-tax) for a partial list).  For the most part, though, residents pay 4.95% of their Federal AGI minus their personal exemption.

Since you're a part-year resident, you will fill out a form specifically for that which will determine your portion of income owed IL taxes on, and exemptions.  See [Schedule NR](https://www2.illinois.gov/rev/forms/incometax/Documents/currentyear/individual/il-1040-schedule-nr.pdf), and [Schedule NR instructions](https://www2.illinois.gov/rev/forms/incometax/Documents/currentyear/individual/IL-1040-Schedule-NR-Instr.pdf).  You'll end up multiplying your exemptions by the proportion of your income that's attributed to IL, so if it's 1/4 (sept-dec and you had same income all year) you'll get 25% of the $2375.  But again, try to do this online if you can - it's free and quite easy (though I've not done Schedule NR before, so can't promise that is as easy given how many lines it has!)

Comment: thanks for the response.
I have tried online system several times but it is not working for me. I have posted the issue here as a separate question. Please see if you know an answer for that. https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/149508/usa-error-in-online-filling-il-state-income-tax-return