# USA | Error in Online filling IL state income tax return

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, income-tax-refund, illinois

This question is relevant for people in USA only. I am trying to file Illinois state tax return online. I am a first time filer with Illinois (the system is supposed to work for first time filers.). When I fill my SSN as an identifier, it gives me an error shown in the screenshot. It is not a technical error as it is working for others and I have also tried different browsers and network and cleared chache. Is it some policy issue? Do I have to do something else before going at this page?

[image]

Comment: Are you typing the hypens? I would try both way, try typing ssn without hypens, and with hypens. Also make sure no ad blocking script or extension is ON on this page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I enquired about the same situation with Illinois Income Tax department through contact form on their site. There response was that you need to file it in paper for the first time. Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response...